# How to compare the features of all the layers

Tags: python, geometry, qgis

I want to compare the geometry of all the feature of a layer to particular feature's geometry in QGIS.
Here is my code:

```
class geometry_checker(base_prechecker):
    def __init__(self):
        self.target_layer_name = "layer_1"

    def do_geom_check(self, layer, layers):
        layer_name = self.get_layer_name(layer)
        if layer_name == self.target_layer_name:
            iter = layer.getFeatures()
            for feat in iter:
                geom = feat.geometry()
                e = geom.type()
                iter1 = layers.getFeatures()
                for fea in iter1:
                    geom_a = fea.geometry()
                    f = geom.type()
                    if e == f:
                        return True
                    else:
                        return False




q = geometry_checker()
lay = iface.activeLayer()
layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()
print q.do_geom_check(lay)
```

If I run this I am getting None as outout. What I really want is if the geometry type is same it should return True else False.
Somebody pls help me

Comment: when `layer_name == self.target_layer_name` is False it will return None

Comment: Yeah I corrected it. And the code returns 'dict' object has no attribute 'getFeatures'

Comment: Which is self explanatory. you are treating a dictionary as if it were an instance of some class

Comment: Okay. But I want to do this using class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a built in tool that will do this for you at any license level in version 10. It's called the Feature Compare tool. This sounds exactly what you described wanting.
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000004000000

Comment: I want to do this in QGIS

Comment: http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html